# Laravel: .htaccess "remember_me" - cookie 502 error

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-sanctum

I deployd my local Project (Laravel-Sanctum) to a Server and setup an .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
  Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"
  Header set Referrer-Policy "strict-origin"
  Header set Permissions-Policy "fullscreen=(), geolocation=()"
  Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' domain.ch; img-src 'self' data:; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' use.fontawesome.com cdn.jsdelivr.net fonts.googleapis.com; script-src 'self' cdn.jsdelivr.net; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com use.fontawesome.com;"
  Header set Expect-CT enforce,max-age=2592000,report-uri="https://www.domain.ch/report"
```

Now everything works fine, unless I try to set a "remember_me" cookie by laravel-sanctum.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502 ()

My Local project is working fine. If I remove all Security-Headers from Server there is no error and the cookie is set properly.

> remember_web_59b...    httpOnly: yes,  secure: yes

What did I configure wrong?
Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I fount out, the Server responded with

> upstream sent too big header while reading response header from upstream

You can fix it, by Increase the HTTP-Header sent by NGINX

```
proxy_buffer_size          256k;
proxy_buffers              4 256k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size    256k;
```